# Formula nested in loop won't execute properly

Tags: c, while-loop

I'm trying to solve a code to run this series pi = 4 - 4/3 + 4/5 - 4/7 + 4/9 ... and so on. The thing is, as i run with higher values, the function tends to 4, not 3,1415.... The program seem to be running only the greatest value that n assumes. Also i cant make %%.lflf work to set decimals according to a variable, (p). The algorithm seems correct but after days i'm desperate for any help, greatly appreciated.

```
if ( 2 == route ) {
    printf("piseries calculator\n");

    double pi,n,p;

    printf("define precision");
    scanf("%lf",&p);

    n=0;

    while (n++ <= p ) {
        pi = (4) - (n * ( 4 / ( 1 + 2 *(n)))) +( n * ( 4 / ( 3 + 2 * (n))));
    }
    printf("%%.lflf",p,pi);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your formula implementation is just wrong. You are just recalculating something you call `pi` each iteration, forgetting the previous values.

Comment: @EugeneSh is right maybe you intended to write `pi+=`

Comment: @Idle001 Not only that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, make n and p integers.

Secondly n starts at 3 doesn't it?

Third the Pi series is 4.0 (- fraction + fraction)...

Finally you can printf using %.*lf to increase/limit the precision of the output.

```
 if ( 2 == route )
 {
    printf("piseries calculator\n");

    double pi=4.0;
    int n,p;

    printf("define precision");
    scanf("%d",&p);

    for(n=3;n<p;n+=2)
    {
        pi -= 4.0/n;
        n+=2;
        pi += 4.0/n;
    }
    printf("%.*lf",p,pi);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: withous scaling those calculations will be very imprecise.

Answer (score 0):

I would scale it as well for those calculations

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define Niterations 1000
#define SCALE 1000

int main(void) {

    double pi = 4.0 * SCALE;
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < Niterations; i ++)
    {
        double f = 4.0 * SCALE / (3 + i * 2);
        pi += (i & 1) ? f : -f;
    }

    printf("N iterations = %u, pi = %lf", Niterations, pi / SCALE);
    // your code goes here
    return 0;
}
```

Test it https://ideone.com/mSZNyg

Result: `N iterations = 10000, pi = 3.141692643590519029572760700830258429050445556640625000000000 ...`